# How to check where in your text file you found a string

Tags: c#

EDIT: Fixed :) Thanks!

I'm trying to make a login code and I'm having a bit of trouble at the login function.
I need to check which line a username is located in, within a text file. Is it possible? If not is there another way around this?

EDIT: added code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int loginAttempt = 0;

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine();
        }

        int userType = 0;
        string retrievedUsername = String.Empty;

        using (System.IO.StreamReader fileUsername = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt"))
        {
            retrievedUsername = fileUsername.ReadToEnd();
        }



        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine("Please note that this is a prototype, passwords are not hashed/encrypted ^_^. Report any bugs / flaws with this to andrew.yu6@hotmail.com, If I get any spam I will high five you in the face with a chair");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; 
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the meData service! Ver. 0.01 Beta, made by mechron");
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter login below or type register to register a new account on this device");
            string loginUsername = Console.ReadLine();
            if (loginUsername == "login")
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Type in your username");
                string loginUser = Console.ReadLine();

            }
            else
            {
                if (loginUsername == "register")
                {
                    int registerAttempt = 0;

                    Console.WriteLine("Choose your username!");
                    string registerUsername = Console.ReadLine();

                    bool containUser = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt").Contains(registerUsername);
                    if (containUser == true) { Console.WriteLine("Error, username already exists! Please try again!"); } else { registerAttempt = 1; }


                    if( registerAttempt == 1 ) 
                   {
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt", true))
                    {
                        files.WriteLine(registerUsername);
                    }

                   }
                    if (registerAttempt == 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Now choose your password!");
                        string loginPass = Console.ReadLine();
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Public\\Passwords.txt", true))
                        {
                            files.WriteLine(loginPass);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Good! Now you will be returned to the start screen! Try to login there!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, command not recognized. Try again");
                }


            }
        } while ( loginAttempt == 0 );
```

Comment: do you want the line no?

Comment: It would help if you could include a sample of your code which you use for finding the string, then we can suggest how to adapt that to get the line number

Comment: You say "the line I found a string in" -- well, how exactly did you find the string? Where is the code? Also, it's highly unlikely that you care about the line number. Perhaps you care about something else that is *related* to the line number? What is that?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I wanted to see if I could find which line a string was in a text file. If that wasn't possible was there another way see whether a username matches a password.

Comment: You are storing plain usernames and passwords in a text file ?! You really should look for another method of authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
if(loginUsername == "login")
{
  Console.WriteLine("Type in your username");
  string loginUser = Console.ReadLine();
  int lineCount=1;
  foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("LoginFile.txt"))
  {
    if(line.Contains(loginUser))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("UserName found in Line No = "+ lineCount);
       break;
    }
       lineCOunt++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are interested in this line of code:

```
bool containUser = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt").Contains(registerUsername);
```

No, this will not tell you the line number. You have to do it yourself using a loop.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Public\\Usernames.txt")
int line_number= 0;
for(;line_number< lines.Length; line_number++)
{
    if(lines[line_number] == registeredUser)
        break;
}

//Your line number is now contained in line_number
```